# How to redirect in "NEW" tab with meta

Tags: html, redirect, meta

Ho can we redirect a page in new tab when we use meta tag. For ex. i am trying this code

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://www.example.com >`

but it redirects it in same page.
And if i add the following code after the url then also nothing happens

`target = "_blank"`

Please help me.

Comment: You can't do that with a meta redirect. use JavaScript

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">window.open('http://example.com');</script>` will do the work

Comment: There are two problems by this : How can i add a waiting time to it and the second that google chrome is showing "POPUP BLOCKED" and not allowing it to open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=javascript:window.open('http://google.com','_blank');">
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript) is related to your question.

Comment: When i add this to my HTML it stills and do not redirect.

Comment: @AhmadTaha Try this link: http://www.paulsilver.co.uk/code/html_working_popup.php