# How to open a url in new window without a href but using content & url attributes

Tags: javascript, url, target

I am using below code to open a new url, however my target="_blank" tag is not working and the site loads into the same page. Please help me.

---

```
  <meta http-equiv = "refresh" content = "3; url = https://www.test.com" target="_blank"/>
```

Comment: Actually what I need is to open the site in a new window instead of opening in the current window

Answer (score 0):

This answer might work for you: [How to redirect in "NEW" tab with meta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30025594/how-to-redirect-in-new-tab-with-meta)

For your case, you can try the following solution:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; URL=javascript:window.open('https://test.com','_blank');">`

Regards,

AJ

Comment: Thank you , my problem is solved using above solution. I appreciate your help

Comment: Glad I could help. You can accept the answer to close the question :)

Answer (score 0):

The following will work for you:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; URL=javascript:window.open('https://www.test.com','_blank');">
```